# Set Inline style background image from server via nodejs and jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm looking for a way to set an inline style for an element with background image and dynamic parameter.

for example:

```
div(style={'background-image':'url(data.url.from.server)'})
```

I've tried `#{data.url.from.server}` But it didn't help.

What should I replace with `data.url.from.server` so it'll work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
div(style="background-image: url('#{data.url.from.server}');")
```

I'm not sure why but you were using curly braces after the style tag. Also your quotation marks were incorrect.

Make sure the #{data.url.from.server} is actually serving the correct url to the image and is not undefined.

Comment: No. It doesn't work. It seems like he's looking for  `#{data.url.from.server}` url.

Comment: So when you log `data.url.from.server` what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Well in those cases I had to use `+` for concating params.

So it will be like that:

```
div(style="background-image: url(" + data.Show.ImageUrl + ");")
```